# Deleting a file IF any folders in current directory contain a keyword using batch

Tags: string, batch-file, directory, find, wildcard

I am trying to write a batch file that takes a backup using temporary folders and a "**sub-batch**" file that needs to be deleted once all backups are completed.

The method I'm trying to use copies a batch file to the main directory, opens multiple instances of this batch which create "temp" folders, then they remove the temp folder once they are done their business.

I want to implement a command at the end of the **sub-batch** that checks if any folders with the word "temp" exist in the directory, then delete the **sub-batch** if none exist.

I have tried many iterations, but this is what I kind of ended at before asking this question:

```
rd %TempFolder% /S /Q

cd C:\BackupDirectory
if exist C:\BackupDirectory\*_Temp_*\ goto :unconnect
del subBatch.bat
:unconnect
```

I realize that this won't work, but I can't find a good way to find the string "temp" in the sub-directory name.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Will the temp directory always be in the BackUPDirectory or could it be nested even further down?

Comment: @Squashman No, the temporary folders always get deleted at the end of execution.  So, while 8 iterations of the batch file are executing, when the first one completes, it should skip deleting the batch from the directory.  Only the very last iteration will delete the batch file.

Comment: You could probably replace `if exist C:\BackupDirectory\*_Temp_*\ goto :unconnect` and `del subBatch.bat` with `Dir "*Temp*">Nul 2>&1&&Del "subBatch.bat"`

Comment: @Compo I'm not very fluent in the language used, so could you explain some of this syntax? I tried it as is and by adding spaces, but I don't even know where the necessary whitespace goes for this syntax... 

Comment: Joshua, I asked you to replace two lines with one, I didn't suggest you change anything or add any whitespace. In the `6` lines of code you posted, delete lines `4` and `5`. You'll then have `4` lines; in between lines `3` and `4` add the line of code I gave you at the bottom of my last comment; that's it!